# Salvar dados de um formulário web em .txt no servidor ftp

Tags: php

Estou com problemas ao salvar meus dados em um .txt no meu servidor FTP.

Localmente consegui tranquilo. Abaixo está o código que estou utilizando localmente:

```
$arquivo = 'msg.txt';     
$criar = fopen($arquivo, "a+"); 
$conteudo = "$nome; $idade; $sexo; $telefone;".PHP_EOL ; 
$escrever = fwrite($criar, $conteudo);
```

Porém eu preciso escrever em um .txt que está em meu servidor FTP.

Já vi que indicando o caminho do arquivo com HTTP não irá funcionar, porém não achei uma solução de como devo fazer o link para o servidor FTP.

O código que estou utilizando para tentar fazer a comunicação online com o .txt é o mesmo, só muda uma linha, que é o caminho do arquivo.

```
$arquivo = 'www.domain.net/pasta/arquivo.txt';
```

A seguinte mensagem de erro é mostrada (com HTTP):

```
failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for de um formulário tente isto:

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' )
{
        var_dump( $_FILES );//apenas para debug

        $servidor = 'host';
        $caminho_absoluto = '/httpdocs/uploads/'; //diretorio do FTP que pode variar dependendo da hospedagem
        $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];

        $con_id = ftp_connect($servidor) or die( 'Não conectou em: '.$servidor );
        ftp_login( $con_id, 'usuario', 'senha' );

        ftp_put( $con_id, $caminho_absoluto.$arquivo['name'], $arquivo['tmp_name'], FTP_BINARY );
}
?>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="arquivo" />
                <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
```

Nesse exemplo é pra fazer upload do arquivo, mas você pode fazer alterações no formulário e PHP para ser escritor numa **TEXTAREA**

Agora se quiser subir/transferir um arquivo da sua hospedagem diretamente para o servidor:

```
<?php
$file = 'somefile.txt'; //arquivo de origem na hospedagem
$remote_file = 'readme.txt'; //nome do arquivo de destino, nome gerado ao enviar para FTP

$conn_id = ftp_connect("host ftp");
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "usuario", "senha");

// Enviar arquivo
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
 echo "Houve um problema ao enviar o arquivo <i><u>$file</u></i>\n";
}

// Encerra acesso ao FTP
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Se quiser deletar o arquivo gerado na hospedagem após enviar a cópia pro FTP use esse comando:

```
unlink($file);
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. Acho que eu não soube definir bem o que necessito. Vamos lá! 

Preciso salvar dados de um formulário web em um arquivo .txt no meu servidor FTP. Por exemplo, na pagina do meu site quando o usuário enviar as informações, as mesmas devem ser inseridas no .txt para que depois eu possa importar para o Excel. Não possuo BD, por isso o uso do .txt, e por se tratar de fácil manipulação desses dados no Excel.

Pelo que entendi, o exemplo que me passou é para fazer upload né ? Na verdade eu preciso escrever no arquivo txt quando o usuário clicar em enviar :/

Comment: Mas no segundo exemplo você faz isso. Gera o arquivo na hospedagem e em seguida envia. A não ser que você não saiba fazer um formulário.

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigado !

Comment: Esqueci de apresentar uma coisa interessante, mas é opcional, se quiser deletar o arquivo gerado na hospedagem após já ter a cópia no FTP use a função unlink() - Editei a resposta pra você analisar